# importing from a Json file

Tags: javascript, typescript, lottie

I am trying to import from a Json file, and pass the resulting import to a function who takes a string. In code I am doing something like:

```
import animation from "assets\lottie\animation.json"
const LottieRef = useLottie(animation);
```

where `useLottie: (path: string) => HTMLDivElement | null` . However I am getting the error which basically says that animation is not of the type string. What should I do with this?

Comment: Your `import` is returning `animation` AS a a JavaScript Object parsed from the JSON content of "...animation.json". It is ready to use AS IS. So, `animation` is an `Object`, not a `String`. Have you tried serializing the object `useLottie(JSON.stringify(animation))`?

Comment: I see. I modified the function to take an Object and now it works! Do you wanna copy and paste your comment to form an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, your `import` is returning `animation` *AS A* JavaScript Object parsed from the JSON content of "...animation.json". It is ready to use *AS IS*. So, `animation` is an Object, not a String.

You could either serialize the object:

```js
useLottie(JSON.stringify(animation))
```

Or better, you could pass it in as animation data:

```js
useLottie({ animationData: animation })
```

This was covered in the [README](https://github.com/vaclav-zeman/use-lottie#readme).